# PostgreSQL and psycopg2: syntax error at or near ";"

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, create-table

I'm trying to duplicate db from mySQL to Postgres by python code, but it shows me an error from PostgreSQL
"syntax error at or near ";""
in CREATE step
I can't understand what is wrong, becouse the same script works in postgres widow:

```
for table in mysql_tables:
    table_name = table[0]
    mysql_cursor.execute(f"DESCRIBE {table_name}")
    mysql_columns = mysql_cursor.fetchall()
    columns = [f'{column[0]} ' for column in mysql_columns]
    query = sql.SQL(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS incomes.{table_name} \n({','.join(columns)}) \nTABLESPACE     pg_default; \nALTER TABLE IF EXISTS income.proxy_list \nOWNER to postgres;")
    print (query)
    postgres_cursor.execute(query)

    mysql_cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}")
    rows = mysql_cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
        query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ({','.join(['%s']*len(row))})"
        postgres_cursor.execute(query, row)
```

and error:
syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 3: TABLESPACE pg_default;

I tryed to delete ";", i tryed to delete all after "({','.join(columns)})", but it showed error near ")" or near " ", i tryed to add "\n" after each line, but nothing changed

Comment: **Do not use** use `f` strings. For parameters use [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and for dynamic SQL use the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete generated CREATE TABLE statement. Not that `TABLESPACE pg_default` is pretty much useless. You can just remove it, to have less noise in the code.

Comment: It seems you are blindly copying the MySQL syntax to Postgres. This won't work. The two DBMS have different syntax and a different set of data types. E.g. `int(10)`, `datetime`, `tinyint` or `enum` won't work on Postgres.